# Is there a NetLogo model that shows collision detection realistically?

Tags: collision-detection, simulation, netlogo

I'm working on a simulation of pedestrian motion and I can't find examples in the library or online that shows collision detection perfectly (like no triangular agents intersect with another agent's triangular shape). Any help?

Comment: There's http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/GasLabCircularParticles which does mathematically correct, billiard-ball style collision of circular particles. This approach is probably overkill for simulating pedestrians, though.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you try to reformulate the problem to work with the Patches, rather than the moving agents.

There is an example in the Model library (under code examples) of Only One Turtle per Patch (or similar).  You can define the patches to be smaller than your agents to improve the resolution of the interactions, and then apply rules that ensure that an agent does not move into a patch that is occupied, or does not infringe on the "neighbour" buffer zone around another agent.

Although this is an approximation (patches are square) so is a triangular agent an approximation to a pedestrian.